# Copiar um ficheiro binário para outro em C

Tags: c, struct, binary

Boas!
Estou a criar um programa de gestão de carros, e necessito de primeiro inserir os meus carros (structs) num ficheiro binário (rascunho), e depois usar outra função para atualizar, e passar os structs desse binario para outro (binario definitivo).

Neste caso os structs tem uma variavel  "eliminar", e os únicos structs que passam para o meu binário definitivo são os que (eliminar == 1). E o ficheiro definitivo tem sempre de fazer um reset e ficar apenas com os structs que o ficheiro rascunho lhe passa, apagando qualquer conteudo lá presente anteriormente.

Não consigo achar o erro, mas o ficheiro definitivo não está a receber nada.

Estes sãos os meus structs:

```
    struct Carro
{
char Marca[30];
char Modelo[30];
char Cor[30];
int Numero;
int eliminar;
} ficha[200];
```

Este é a minha função para atualizar:

```
    FILE *fp, *fpdef;
    int retorno, i = 1;
    fpdef = fopen("Dados.bin","a");
    fp = fopen("Rascunho.bin", "rb");


    printf("\n =========================================");
    printf("\n =              Atualizar                =");
    printf("\n =========================================");


    retorno = fread(&ficha[i], sizeof(struct Carro), 1, fp);
    while ( retorno == 1) 
    {
        if(ficha[i].eliminar == 1)
        {
            fwrite(&ficha[i], sizeof(struct Carro), 1, fpdef);
        }
        i++;
    retorno = fread(&ficha[i], sizeof(struct Carro), 1, fp);
    }


    printf("\n\n\n Ficheiro Atualizado com sucesso!\n\n");
    system("pause");
    system("CLS");
    main();     
}
```

Agradeço pela Ajuda! :)

Answer (score -1):

O int i começa em 0 em fez de 1, não estás a utilizar a primeira posicão do vector.

Isto está na manpage do fread: On success, fread() and fwrite() return the number of items read or written. **This number equals the number of bytes transferred only when size is 1.**

Pode ser que a tua **condição do while esteja errada**, experimenta colocar o **while >= 1**, pode ser que resolva.

Espero que te tenha ajudado.